# Unable to Uninstall Bitdefender

Tags: bitdefender

I am unable to uninstall Bitdefender, even with the tool provided by Bitdefender, because no one can remember the password used to "protect" the installation. I cannot boot into safe mode either, because my computer manages to start up successfully about 1 in a million times.

Bitdefender keeps starting up on my computer, and I cannot stop it through Services due to an "Access Denied" error message. I downloaded Process Hacker 2 today and finally managed to kill the Bitdefender process, but I am still unable to uninstall or get Bitdefender to stop starting up with the computer.

Is there any way to take BitDefender off? I am the administrator on my computer but have no control over it. I am on Windows 10 home edition.

Comment: Sounds like something you should ask BitDefender about. Antiviruses are notoriously difficult to uninstall without correct permissions.

Comment: You can use Advanced Startup to boot into Safe Mode 100% of the time.  "Is there any way to take BitDefender off?" - You can reinstall Windows 10 from within Windows and choose NOT to keep our personal files.  Yes; I understand this might not be the solution you want to use, but it is a solution that will work, but only after additional attempts to remember the password required to uninstall the product in question